# Pulling variable from Dynamic Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a game lobby where when a user creates a game, their username and how much in game currency they are betting on the game appears on the screen for all players to see in a RecyclerView.

So in this case, a user named 'Brent_MB' created a game

[image]

But the issue is the player put a wager of 2.00 on the game and it won't appear. (2.50 is the default number that appears)

This is what my database structure looks like

[image]

So, since this database is so dynamic, it literally changes each time someone wants to play a game and it gets deleted when the game starts, how can I go about assigning the wager value to the slot that currently says '2.50'

This is what I have tried to do:

I have created a callback for the wager variable like this,

```
public void getWager(final WagerCallback wagerCallback) {
    FCGames.child("What do I put here to check each node every time a node is added")
            .child("wager").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                wagerr = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                String wagerD = Double.toString(wagerr);
                wage = wagerD.endsWith("0");

                wagerCallback.onCallback(wagerD);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

I also have a Callback interface with this but it doesn't seem relevant.

and then I call this method in my RecyclerView class like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    String userName = mData.get(position);
    holder.userName.setText(userName);
    holder.bind(mData.get(position), position, listener);

        fcl.getWager(new FlipCoinLobby.WagerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String wager) {
                holder.wager.setText(wager);
            }
        });

}
```

As you can see, in this line I am stuck on what to put as the first child so that it can check each child when it is added and get that wager value. \

```
FCGames.child("What do I put here to check each node every time a node is added").child("wager")
```

What should I put there so that it can get the wager value from each node and appropriately assign it to the text view area?

Each initial node in the FCGames database is stored in an ArrayList called openGames. I can show how nodes are added to that list if necessary

```
wages.add(wagerD);

for(int i=0; i <= openGames.size(); i++) {
   wagerCallback.onCallback(wages.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the key of the child node you're trying to load, you have two options:

1. Load all child nodes of `FCGames`.
2. Load the first/last child node of `FCGames`.

I'll show the second option, as the first is easy to derive from that:

```
FCGames.orderByKey()
       .limitToFirst(1)
       .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            wagerr = snapshot.child("wager").getValue(Long.class);
            String wagerD = Double.toString(wagerr);
            wage = wagerD.endsWith("0");

            wagerCallback.onCallback(wagerD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

The biggest differences are:

- I use a query to get the first key only.
- I then need to use a loop in `onDataChange`, since queries *can* have multiple results (event though this one won't).

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the detailed response! My questions are: are the first and second options you offered synonymous in what they end up doing? I implemented the second option, like you showed, and if there are 2 games created then they both display the wager of the first game. Is that was the .limitToFirst(1) is doing?

Comment: The `onDataChange` on the code I shared will only be called with a single child node. If you want it to be called for each child node, remove the `.orderByKey()
       .limitToFirst(1)` from my code (which brings you to the first solution). I highly recommend spending some time reading about Firebase queries btw, as what I'm doing here are fairly basic examples of that.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I know, I have a lot to learn and generally I prematurely ask questions (before doing enough research), I am working on that and appreciate your patience and assistance. Every problem you, and other users, help me solve is another thing I learn about various things.

Comment: You're welcome Brent. The best you can do to help us help you is isolating your problem in a so-called MCVE. To learn what that is, and how it's helpful for both you and us, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am having an issue with this still, and I am not sure why. The for loop always sets the wager value to the last node in my database. So if i have a user with the name 'zach' create a game, and a user named 'brent' create a game, the wager's both reflect the wager of 'zach' because he is the last node. I would understand why this was happening if I had .limitToLast() in place but I do not.

Comment: You only have one variable `wagerr`. So it will have whatever value you last assign to it. Try printing the value of `wagerr` in the loop, and you'll see it having each value in turn.

Comment: I have been working on storing each value and assigning it to the right spot, and my solution has been to add each wage to a list, and then in another for loop I am getting each value in the list of wagers up until the list size reaches the size of the game list. This is what it looks like `added it to the bottom of the post` It is not working right at the moment, but am I onto something here lol? Is this the right thought process